# Making my site responsive by hiding thumbnails_wrapper when site is viewed on mobile or tablet

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm **relatively new to programming** and am struggling with some CSS. I have thumbnails navigation bar in my site (#thumbnails_wrapper) and want to hide it completely when the **screen size drops below a width** of say 700px.

With my limited CSS knowledge, I've tried to have a go myself, but the following code just hides the wrapper completely on any screen - including a full sized desktop screen.

```
@media (min-width:700px){
    #thumbnails_wrapper {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Jack

Answer (score 1):

Your current CSS is targeting anything with a browser window width GREATER than 700px.

Change `min-width` to `max-width`

```
@media (max-width:700px){
    #thumbnails_wrapper {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Indeed. `@media (min-width:700px)` means "Apply these styles only to a viewport with a *minimum width* of 700px".